# Facebook "Publish Story" dialog buttons are too far down

Tags: iphone, dialog, facebook-graph-api

I have the following problem with my implementation of Facebook.

I want to publish a user story and everything works pretty well except sometimes the buttons
are placed too far down and you can't just scroll them up 'cause they always will pop back down there. I think you can see it best in the picture!

Its even worse in German...

Does anybody have the same problems? Or does anybody know why this could be?

**[Screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14257606/Screenshot_3.png)**

Comment: I have the same problem and it is driving me crazy... :-(  no clue...

Comment: same here!! please let me know if you find anything! I also tryed the testapp from fb! same problem so I guess it is a bug in de fb SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright it is gone now!
There was a new update of the Facebook api and this problem went away after updating! 
So like I thought it was a problem of the Facebook api!

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the size of your content.Since this is a webview so it adjust the size as per your content.Decrease the size of your content and they were , on their right position.

Hope it helps you.....

Comment: this is not the problem I think. cause if it would be the too long content then I would be able to scroll down and see the buttons but that is not the case. I scroll down, the buttons scroll up and a visible and as soon as you release the scroll the pop down and the space is filled with blank space. so if you do that a couple of times the whitespace gets more and more but the buttons are never touchable cause the always pop down again

Comment: oh and second its like I said not all the time sometimes it is displayed perfectly correct

Answer (score -1):

I have narrowed it down somewhat:
feed dialog is scrambled only when called right after login dialog. In my case when user clicks post button I check if he is logged in, if yes then show post feed dialog, if not I show him login dialog then post feed dialog. 
There is no need to do that because post feed dialog will force user to login when opening...

skipping this step with login solved this problem...

Comment: I use Single-Sign-On (SSO) the user only has to login once or be logged in in the facbook app. don't you use SSO?

Comment: Nope, disabled it because I had some problems when app was leaving foreground with socket reusing, but that is totally different story.. :-D

Comment: But if you dont use SSO just show the dialog you never get to user authorization dialog right ? the user just logs in an thats it right ?

Comment: first time you request app access you get that dialog, user makes choice and it never bugs him again...

Comment: can you please post a new answer with code how you did it ? i dont get that authorization dialog!

Comment: '  [_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:parameters andDelegate:self];' parameters is NSDictionary with fb parameters described at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: @kviksilver I do the same but for whatever reason I only get the login dialog! I never get a authorization dialog! I have no idea why